# Get multiple regex match result all in one match by Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make my code looks professional by removing those duplicate code. the question is I want to get some data from a string, to be specific, I need to know the `NUMBER`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `A`, `B`, etc. values but the regex expression are different for each variable so I have to repeat myself writing a lot of duplicate code.

```js
let TextString = `DRILL(NUMBER:=20,NAME:='4',PN:=1,X:=10.1,Y:=73.344,Z:=0,A:=-1.435,B:=1.045,M1:=1,M2:=2,M3:=3,M4:=4,M5:=1,S1:=10.5,S2:=2.1,S3:=1.2,S4:=2,S5:=2.4,RS1:=1,RS2:=2);`;
const regNumber = /(?<=NUMBER:=)[0-9]+/gm;
let lineNumber = Number(TextString.match(regNumber));

const regX = /(?<=X:=)(-?[0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)?/gm;
let X = Number(TextString.match(regX)).toFixed(1);

const regY = /(?<=Y:=)(-?[0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)?/gm;
let Y = Number(TextString.match(regY)).toFixed(1);

const regZ = /(?<=Z:=)(-?[0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)?/gm;
let Z = Number(TextString.match(regZ)).toFixed(1);

const regA = /(?<=A:=)(-?[0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)?/gm;
let A = Number(TextString.match(regA)).toFixed(1);

const regB = /(?<=B:=)(-?[0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)?/gm;
let B = Number(TextString.match(regB)).toFixed(1);
// and many more duplicate code.

console.log(lineNumber, X, Y, Z, A, B);
```

I could only think of a way like the above, to match each variable individually and run `.match()` multiple times, but as you can see there are 17 variables total and in real situations, there are hundreds of these `TextString`. I was worried that this matching process will have a huge impact on performance.

Are there any other ways to fetch all variables in one match and store them in an array or object? or any other elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Thank you @Michael M. for the modification on my grammar and also add a run code snippet, I did not know there is a function like this, this is very helpful, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every value match a pattern `:=[value],` or `:=[value])` for the last one. So there is my regex

> (?<=:=)-?[\d\w.']+(?=[,)])

- Positive Lookbehind `(?<=:=)` look for match behind `:=`
- `-?` match `-` optional (for negative number)
- `[\d\w.']+`: match digit, word character, `.`, `'`
- Positive Lookahead `(?=[,)])` look for match ahead character `,` or `)`

[Live regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ4tHs/1)

Now change your code to

```
 let TextString = `DRILL(NUMBER:=20,NAME:='4',PN:=1,X:=10.1,Y:=73.344,Z:=0,A:=-1.435,B:=1.045,M1:=1,M2:=2,M3:=3,M4:=4,M5:=1,S1:=10.5,S2:=2.1,S3:=1.2,S4:=2,S5:=2.4,RS1:=1,RS2:=2);`;
 const regexPattern= /(?<=:=)-?[\d\w.']+(?=[,)])/g;
 console.log(TextString.match(regexPattern))
 // ['20', "'4'", '1', '10.1', '73.344', '0', '-1.435', '1.045', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '10.5', '2.1', '1.2', '2', '2.4', '1', '2']
```

**Edit**

I just realized the the Positive Lookahead is unnecessary as @Peter Seliger
mentioned

> (?<=:=)-?[\d\w.']+

Change your regex pattern to

```
const regexPattern= /(?<=:=)-?[\d\w.']+/g;
```

Comment: I finally choice this one as the best answer because this is the shortest answer with a totally new regex. all other answers also works, but for a beginner like me, other answers are a little bit too complex or influenced by my bad regex sample. but this is more of my skill problem, not their issue. Thank you all!

Comment: @Bonnypro ... a regex which features a positive lookbehind is neither needed [nor is it supported by safari](https://caniuse.com/?search=positive%20lookbehind)

Answer (score 1):

Every coordinate will have a single letter identifier, so you can use a more general positive lookback `(?<=,[A-Z]:=)`. This lookback matches a comma followed by a single uppercase letter then the equality symbol.

You can then use `.match()` to get all matches and use `.map()` to run the conversion you were doing.

```js
let TextString = `DRILL(NUMBER:=20,NAME:='4',PN:=1,X:=10.1,Y:=73.344,Z:=0,A:=-1.435,B:=1.045,M1:=1,M2:=2,M3:=3,M4:=4,M5:=1,S1:=10.5,S2:=2.1,S3:=1.2,S4:=2,S5:=2.4,RS1:=1,RS2:=2);`;
const regNumber = /(?<=NUMBER:=)[0-9]+/gm;
let lineNumber = Number(TextString.match(regNumber));

const regex = /(?<=,[A-Z]:=)(-?[0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)?/gm;
let coord = TextString.match(regex).map(n => Number(n).toFixed(1));

console.log(lineNumber, coord);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a single pattern:

```
(?<=\b(?:NUMBER|[XYZAB]):=)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left of the current position is

  - `\b(?:NUMBER|[XYZAB]):=` Match either `NUMBER` or one of `X` `Y` `Z` `A` `B` preceded by a word boundary and followed by `:=`
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `-?` Match an optional `-`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits and an optional decimal part
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1FF4pL/1).

```js
const TextString = `DRILL(NUMBER:=20,NAME:='4',PN:=1,X:=10.1,Y:=73.344,Z:=0,A:=-1.435,B:=1.045,M1:=1,M2:=2,M3:=3,M4:=4,M5:=1,S1:=10.5,S2:=2.1,S3:=1.2,S4:=2,S5:=2.4,RS1:=1,RS2:=2);`;
const regNumber = /(?<=\b(?:NUMBER|[XYZAB]):=)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b/g;
const result = TextString
  .match(regNumber)
  .map(s =>
    Number(s).toFixed(1)
  );
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach could be based on a regex pattern which utilizes [capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups). The matching regex for the OP's sample text would look like this ...

```js
/\b(NUMBER|[XYZAB])\:=([^,]+),/g
```

... and the description is provided with the [regex' test site](https://regex101.com/r/7kWfS0/2).

The pattern is both simple and generic. The latter is due to always capturing both the matching `key` like `Number` and its related `value` like `20`. Thus it doesn't matter where a key-value pair occurs within a drill-data string.

Making use later of an object based [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#syntax) for assigning all of the OP's variables at once the post processing task needs to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the result array of [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) into  an object which features all the captured keys and values. Within this task one also can control how the values are computed and/or whether or how the keys might get sanitized.

```js
const regXDrillData = /\b(NUMBER|[XYZAB])\:=([^,]+),/g;
const textString =
  `DRILL(NUMBER:=20,NAME:='4',PN:=1,X:=10.1,Y:=73.344,Z:=0,A:=-1.435,B:=1.045,M1:=1,M2:=2,M3:=3,M4:=4,M5:=1,S1:=10.5,S2:=2.1,S3:=1.2,S4:=2,S5:=2.4,RS1:=1,RS2:=2);`;

// - processed values via reducing the captured
//   groups of a `matchAll` result array of a
//   generic drill-data match-pattern.
const {
  number: lineNumber,
  x, y, z,
  a, b,
} = [...textString.matchAll(regXDrillData)]
  .reduce((result, [match, key, value]) => {
    value = Number(value);
    value = (key !== 'NUMBER') ? value.toFixed(1) : value;
    return Object.assign(result, { [ key.toLowerCase() ]: value });
  }, {})

console.log(
`processed values via reducing the captured
groups of a 'matchAll' result array of a
generic drill-data match-pattern ...`,
  { lineNumber, x, y, z, a, b },
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! this answer seems more flexible and can add many more functions in future. and thanks for the reading materials.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using a `.reduce()` on keys of interest and returns an object:

```js
const TextString = `DRILL(NUMBER:=20,NAME:='4',PN:=1,X:=10.1,Y:=73.344,Z:=0,A:=-1.435,B:=1.045,M1:=1,M2:=2,M3:=3,M4:=4,M5:=1,S1:=10.5,S2:=2.1,S3:=1.2,S4:=2,S5:=2.4,RS1:=1,RS2:=2);`;
const keys = [ 'NUMBER', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B' ];

let result = keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
  const regex = new RegExp('(?<=\\b' + key + ':=)-?[0-9.]+');
  obj[key] = Number(TextString.match(regex)).toFixed(1);
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
{
  "NUMBER": "20.0",
  "X": "10.1",
  "Y": "73.3",
  "Z": "0.0",
  "A": "-1.4",
  "B": "1.0"
}
```

**Notes:**

- The regex is built dynamically from the key
- A `\b` word boundary is added to the regex to reduce the chance of unintended matches
- If you need the line number as an integer you could take that out of the `keys`, and handle it separately.